# FastMM 64-bit "The block header has been corrupted"

Tags: delphi, fastmm

Latest FastMM4 4.991, XE2, was trying to solve memory leaks and got this error under FullDebugMode + LogErrorsToFile settings. 
Error

```
The current thread ID is 0x7C4, and the stack trace (return addresses) leading to this error is:
41B914 [FastMM4][CheckFreeBlockUnmodified$qqrrp29Fastmm4.TFullDebugBlockHeaderui23Fastmm4.TBlockOperation]
41B996 [FastMM4][DebugGetMem$qqri]
41BD1F [FastMM4][DebugReallocMem$qqrrpvi]
40615D [System.pas][System][@ReallocMem$qqrrpvi][3524]
40CF62 [System.pas][System][@UStrSetLength$qqrr20System.UnicodeStringi][24163]
40D057 [System.pas][System][@UStrCat$qqrr20System.UnicodeStringrx20System.UnicodeString][24290]
8127D6 [LogHandler.pas][LogHandler][AddCustomLog$qqruiuii][160]
...
```

Code is quite simple and was used in several projects without any errors

```
procedure AddCustomLog(p1, p2: NativeUInt; MsgType: integer);
const
  MSG_LEN = 200;
var
  ErrorString: array [0 .. MSG_LEN] of Char;
  i: integer;
  temp: string;
  descr: UTF8String;
  b: byte;
  pb: PByte;
begin
  case MsgType of
    ...
    BUFFER_LOG: begin
        temp := 'len = ' + IntToStr(p2) + ' buf : ' + sLineBreak;
        descr := '';
        pb := PByte(p1);

        for i := 0 to p2 - 1 do begin
          b := pb^;
          // if i = 27 then LogAllocatedBlocksToFile(0, 0);
          temp := temp + format('%.2X ', [b]); //IntToHex(b, 2) + ' ';
          if ((b >= $20) and (b < $80)) or (b >= $C0) then
              descr := descr + UTF8Encode(AnsiChar(b))
          else
              descr := descr + '.';

          if (i mod $10) = $F then begin
            temp := temp + '  |  ' + UTF8ToString(descr) + sLineBreak;
            descr := '';
          end;
          inc(pb);
        end;

        if length(temp) > 0 then
            AddToLog(temp + '  |  ' + UTF8ToString(descr));
      end;
  end;
end;
```

FastMM raises "Out of memory" exception at `temp := temp + format('%.2X ', [b]);` with `format` or `IntToHex`. Call stack leads to _UStrCat, _UStrSetLength, _ReallocMem. Always at `i = 27`. Parameter for `p1` is address of TBytes array 128 bytes length filled with 41 bytes ( NativeUInt(@FData[0]) ).
I've tried to put memory access breakpoint to 7FFFFE62540 (address from FastMM message "Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7FFFFE62540"), traced this memory block from application start: it is empty unused area up to memory block creation at address 7FFFFE62450 and address 7FFFFE62540 filled as ptr + f0 by FastMM (when `i = 27`). After checking this block for control sum FastMM fails (traced in CPU Window).
Also I've tried to exclude this log part but got similar exception at simple `inherited` Create of one of objects (far after this code execution). Also happens only under `FullDebugMode`.

Finally I tried to build and check this project with same options and `FastMM4Options.inc` under 32-bit `Target Platforms` - there is no errors at all. Everything is fine. Except I can't debug it under Windows 7-64.

So is there any errors in code or known bugs in FastMM? I've spent 3 days tracing it and have no other ideas what to do (even tried to replace first 4 GB memory in slots, 4 x 2048). Used FastMM_FullDebugMode64.dll and FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll from FastMM4. Thanks.

**edit:** It is awful to solve such things but it seems I found strategy for myself (solved, it was drawbacks of `all in one`, same object as different classes depending on OLE or Direct mode, error caused by using object as different class object)
1. Put FastMM4 call to LogAllocatedBlocksToFile(0, 0) right before error should happen
2. Find nearest object in log, for me it was object by address near $300 bytes below error's address
3. Put Data breakpoints to nonzero areas near your error address (for me it was near $40 bytes below). Several breakpoints because big areas like 256 bytes just was not triggered by changes. In this case it was area between the end of nearest object (address + size by log) and error's address.
4. Analyze code on breakpoints.
5. Several runs to find what to track and finally got error code position. Reenable Data breakpoints on each run, because IDE disables them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symptoms you describe are those of a heap corruption. You say the error occurs here:

```
temp := temp + format('%.2X ', [b]);
```

Well, both `temp` and `b` are local variables, and `Format` is known to work correctly. Therefore the only conclusion I would contemplate is that you have, before this code runs, corrupted the heap.

Stop looking at FastMM and focus on your code. Make a simple SSCCE and if you can't solve it from there, we should be able to.

Comment: How to find source of corruption? I've tried everything I found by Google except expensive commercial "we will dump call stack for you". There is no errors with simple application, only with huge project with commercial DAC components where I should add part for SqlServer communication.

Comment: Try to isolate the code that leads to the error. Remove code until the fault disappears. Then look at what you removed. Also, do you have range checking enabled? Perhaps it's nothing more than a simple buffer overrun.

Comment: I've tried "range checking", it raises exception at password for SqlServer encryption only
  if dlen > 0 then begin
    setlength(crypted, dlen);
    pb := PByte(value);
    for i := 0 to dlen - 1 do begin
      crypted[i] := ((pb^ shl 4) or (pb^ shr 4)) xor $A5;
      inc(pb);
    end;
at shl, shr and xor, or maybe because source of pointer is string 1-based.

Comment: Well, that's a clear error isn't it: `crypted[0]` is out of bounds.

Comment: Why? crypted: TBytes; it is dynamic array 0-based, const value: string

Comment: If crypted is `TBytes` then it's not a range check error. I assumed it was a string.

Comment: This line gives me `Exception class ERangeError with message 'Range check error'` if `Range checking` enabled.

Comment: It's going to be hard for me to debug your program in these comments. I'm confident that I answer the question that you asked. I'm afraid that only you can debug your program and find your heap corruption,.

Comment: Any tips what else I can do to find source of corruption without analyzing 2 MB of sources for possible bugs? I think I've tried all I can find about 'The block header has been corrupted'

Comment: What I already said. Isolate the fault by removing code and functionality until the error disappears.

Comment: Found, `howto` in `edit` section of initial question, thanks. Should I mark your answer as correct answer?

Comment: Accept the answer you feel is best. Your choice.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using FastMM4, try setting `FastMM4.FullDebugModeScanMemoryPoolBeforeEveryOperation := true;`  It'll run a full corruption check before every memory operation.  This can really slow things down, but it also makes it much easier to find where something is going wrong: when it reports an error, then at someplace between the last memory operation and the current code, something got corrupted.  This makes your search a lot easier.

Comment: It is already set in dpr for 2 days, everything the same: begin
  // ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := DebugHook <> 0;
  FullDebugModeScanMemoryPoolBeforeEveryOperation := true;
  Application.Initialize;
... Also I dumped memory right before error with LogAllocatedBlocksToFile and can't find any object sharing this memory block.